# WinJS cache facebook profile pricture

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I made a Facebook game for Windows 8 where users can connect to Facebook and share their scores.

When users close the game and later reopen it, I have their UserName and User ID cached; however, I get their image with the graph api url.

My problem occurs when users open my app when they are offline. I can display their name correctly, because it is cached, but I cannot display their image, because it is not cached. How can I cache their image in my WinJS app so that it is still available when they are offline?

Here is my code to show their image:

```
$('#FbUserExterno img').attr('src', 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + RS.getUserId() + '/picture');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point you are connected, download the image file and save it locally (using [WinJs.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br229787.aspx), for instance).

You can then use the [ms-appdata:///local/](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781229.aspx) scheme for the image source pointing to the downloaded file in local storage.

Of course, you'll want to refresh the image in local storage at some frequency, perhaps re-downloading it when you detect you have a network connection.

Comment: Great! Do you know how can i detect if i have a network connection?

Comment: take a look at [this Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh452991(v=win.10).aspx)